# Can't send/receive post data to API Server Anugularjs

Tags: angularjs, ruby, rest, post, sinatra

Could someone please try to assist me ? This has been racking my brain for quite sometime and I've googled and searched Stack for solutions but was unable to find anything  that works.

I am fairly new to web dev but I've been focusing more on the back-end but wanted to try a little front-end so I decided (using an online tutorial) to create a server/client rest api using a card game with all game logic on the server(ruby/sinatra) which accepts/sends json data to and from the client(angularjs). I can successfully test the api using rest-client but can't seem to get it to work using angularjs. Below is my successful rest-client data validation and my failed angularjs client side app. I simply(so I thought) wanted to be able to type in a players name in a form/text box and send that data to the server and have the server respond with data as setup just like I do in rest-client. Thanks and FYI I have cross_origin enabled on sinatra server side.

Here is server side post route..

```
post '/join' do
return_message = {}
jdata = JSON.parse(params[:data], :symbolize_names => true)
if jdata.has_key?(:name) && cas.join_game(jdata[:name])
return_message[:status] = "Welcome #{jdata[:name]}"
```

Rest-Client side code..

```
class CasinoClient
attr_reader :name

def initialize name
    @name = name
end

def join_game
    response = RestClient.post '/localhost:8080/join', :data => {name: @name}.to_json, :accept => :json
    puts JSON.parse(response,:symbolize_names => true)
end
```

[Rest-Client output in irb..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YnQV.png)

Client side view(not working)..

```
%script{:src => "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"}
%script{:src => "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"}
%body
%div{"ng-app" => "myApp", "ng-controller" => "myCtrl"}
Name:
%input{:name => "uname", "ng-model" => "uname", :type => "text"}
%button{"ng-click" => "SendData()"} Submit
{{ PostDataResponse }}
%script{:src => "casApp.js"}
%script{:src => "casCtrl.js"}
```

Angularjs controller(not working)..

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.SendData = function () {
var data = $.param({
  data: {name: $scope.uname }
});

var config = {
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
    }
}

$http.post('http://localhost:8080/join', data, config)
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
})
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the success function, is it hit? what do you see there? If it is not hit, what happens when you set a breakpoint in the error function (which you'd need to add)? What do you see in the network tab?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't go over all your code, but I found invalid syntax just in the end. you should have a pay attention to the little `.` missing, for the `success` method to be called.

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8080/join', data, config)
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
})
```

Also, you don't have to do the `$.param` with `jquery`, you can let angular do the job. you just do:

```
var data = {
  data: {name: $scope.uname }
};
```

Also, the success function has only one argument, which is an object.

so you have to do:

```
.success(function(res){
        $scope.PostDataResponse = res.data;
    });
```

Comment: sorry the missing `.`was just a typo from coping/pasting over and unfortunately  i've already tried  `var data = ...`  but it didn't work either also tried  `var params = ..`   which led me to `$.params` if i post everything thing i tried this post would be pages long lol thanks tho

Comment: Let's just break down your problem, and see where the error lays, If you look on your console (`ctrl` + `shift` + `j`) on network, do you see your request being requested as expected?

Comment: Hmmm this seems interesting looking into it now I'll keep you posted 
I'm getting Provisional headers are show in Request Headers...

Comment: BTW, why do you need the config? I'm almost certain you can leave it. Just pass the URL and the Params.

Comment: Another debugging tool: try to do '$http.post("http://localhost:8080/join", data).then(console.log).catch(console.log);

Comment: getting rid of the config crap got rid of my provisional headers msg but im still back at square one api not accepting and returning data.

Comment: @EricSupreme than your problem is probably also in the backend code.

Comment: i thought so to but testing with rest-client the backend checks ok see my original post rest client output link...i've also been looking at ngresource model according to angularjs docs it "provides interaction support with RESTful services via the $resource service." may try to rewrite after i study over it a bit it can't hurt anything and thanks for your replies i appreciate it.

Comment: Please have a look of my last recent edit. It might be the final solution, and please accept my answer if solved your problem.